# Express - Como fazer com que o link de logout apareca quando o usuario estiver autenticado

Tags: node.js, express.js, ejs

acabei a autenticação de usuario em meu projeto e gostaria que quando o usuário logasse os links de login e cadastro sumissem e no lugar aparece um link de logout.

obs: Estou usando o ejs para renderizar o projeto.

[Minha rota de autenticação img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DMw1.png)

```
router.post('/authenticate', (req, res) => {

    let email = req.body.email
    let password = req.body.password

    User.findOne({
        where: {
            email: email
        }
    }).then(user => {
        if(user != undefined) { //se existe um usuario com esse email
            // validar senha
            let correct = bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password) // comparando hash de senha
            
            if(correct) {

                req.session.user = {
                    id: user.id,
                    email: user.email,
                    eAdmin: user.eAdmin
                }
                // res.json(req.session.user)
                res.redirect('/articles')
            } else {
                req.flash('error_msg', 'Senha incorreta!')
                res.redirect('/login')
                
            }
        } else {
            req.flash('error_msg', 'Email incorreto!')
            res.redirect('/login')
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Terias que passar uma variável ao teu template com a informação da sessão e de acordo com isso mostrar ou não mostrar o botão de logout.